# Why is self.img being interpreted as an int?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

So, I am trying to load an image and draw it onto a canvas, as in here:

```
    self.field = tk.Canvas(height=310, width=450, bg="white", highlightthickness=0)
    self.field.pack(side=tk.TOP)

    photo = tk.PhotoImage(file=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "Photos","Image.png"))
    self.img = self.field.create_image(155, 225, image=photo)
    print(self.img) # apparently prints "1".
    self.img.image = sprite # blows up with AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'image'
```

However, as in the last line, it draws successfully, but also blows up with the error I mentioned in the last line.

Why is it interpreting a canvas drawing as an int? (as shown in the print line)

**EDIT:** don't mind the format, tkinter weirdly, as in my version supports .png w/o  PIL needed.

Comment: Can you post the entire object?

Comment: `tk.Canvas.create_image` returns the item id, which is an integer

Comment: How do I interpret it as an image? Also, if I take out the error line, the image doesn't show.

Comment: You can't interpret the ID as an image. What are you trying to do with it? If you need to modify what is drawn, the Canvas object has methods to do that, where you pass the object ID in.

Answer (score 2):

It's important to know what the methods you're calling return. In this case, you're calling the create_image method on a tkinter Canvas object (self.field). According to the docs (or at least *some* documentation I found via Google--I'm not super familiar with tkinter):

> This constructor returns the integer ID number of the image object for that canvas.

(http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/create_image.html)

So you're setting self.img to the ID number of the image object within the Canvas object -- not the image object itself which seems to be internal to the Canvas object. For ways to modify the image, check other Canvas methods. It looks like there are functions that use the resulting object ID to modify the item, such as Canvas.itemconfig(...) or Canvas.coords(...).